# Recursive list splitting

Tags: python, recursion

I want to split a list recursively and ultimately store it in a tree like structure.

My goal is to implement this from scratch to really understand and learn, i.e. I am not interested in any module providing that functionality.

The below code is not really working as I am struggling with a recursive function that needs to be called twice (for both sides of the split).
Specifically, I have the following issue with the code:

1. the min_size criteria is not held
2. the output should be in a form that I can trace children (left/right) and parents. How do I implement this in the best way?

Can someone give me some hints how to improve my code that it splits the list recursively correctly.

Any advice will help. Thanks!

```
def _split(data):
    'Dummy function to split data'
    idx = np.random.randint(0,len(data),1)[0]
    lhs, rhs = data[:idx], data[idx:]
    
    return lhs, rhs
    
def tree(data, min_size=2):
        
    out = []
    
    if (len(data) <= min_size):
        
        out.append(data)
        return out
        
    else:
        
        lhs, rhs = _split(data)
    
        out.append(tree(lhs, min_size))
        out.append(tree(rhs, min_size))
        
    return out
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What's the expected result of the code supposed to be? I ran the code just now on an array of 13 numbers and I get this: `[[[[1, 2]], [[3]]], [[[[4]], [[5, 6]]], [[[]], [[[7, 8]], [[[9, 10]], [[11, 12]]]]]]]` Is this something you expect? Are you concerned about the fact that it contains elements that are less than your `min_size`?  Algorithmically your recursive function works.

Comment: this is interesting but i would like to know more clearly what the properties of the output are is there a heirarchal strucutre?

Comment: The problem with some arrays having less than 2 elements comes to your split function. Since you are generating the split index randomly, you can by chance split the array on index 0 or 1 or even one less than the length which would result in arrays of length 0 or 1... If you are trying to fix that you will have to return in your base case for a size of smaller than `2*min_size` (since you can not split anything bellow `2*min_size` into 2 splits both larger than `min_size` and also you will have to modify the split to generate the random split between `min_size` and `len(array)-min_size + 1`.

Comment: @mandulaj. Thanks. I have edited my OP. One aspect is indeed min_size. Your comment helps. The other is how can I trace parent/children nodes?

Comment: @FredMaster incidentally you can get a single random integer by just doing `np.random.randint(0, len(data))`, rather than specifying a size of 1 then indexing.

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky thanks for your response. Yes, it would be great if the output would resemble a hierarchical structure (nested dict?).

Comment: please show an example input and an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting the answer here rather in the comments as it will allow for richer formatting though I doubt it is a full answer...

---

**1. Respecting `min_size`**

As I said in the comment, you have to make sure to not to split arrays that are smaller than `2*min_size` since then you will not be able to split them into two arrays larger or equal to `min_size`. You also have to make sure to limit the split index in order not to randomly create arrays smaller than `min_size`

```
def _split(data, min_size):
    'Dummy function to split data'
    # Create a random split index between `min_size` and `len(data)-min_size`
    idx = np.random.randint(min_size,len(data)-min_size+1)
    lhs, rhs = data[:idx], data[idx:]
    
    return lhs, rhs
    
def tree(data, min_size=2):
    out = []
    
    if (len(data) < 2*min_size):  
        # out.append(data)
        # You do not have to wrap the final layer in another array
        return data
        
    else:
        
        lhs, rhs = _split(data,min_size)
    
        out.append(tree(lhs, min_size))
        out.append(tree(rhs, min_size))
        
    return out
```

Output for an array from 1 to 12 is:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]]]
```

I also implemented an alternative method with dictionaries which might be a little easier to read. But it still doesn't allow for a simple traversal up the tree.

```
def tree2(data, min_size=2):
    
    if (len(data) < 2*min_size):  
        # out.append(data)
        # You do not have to wrap the final layer in another array
        return data
        
    else:
        
        lhs, rhs = _split(data,min_size)
        return {
            "left": tree2(lhs, min_size),
            "right": tree2(rhs, min_size)
        }
```

Output:

```
{'left': [1, 2], 'right': {'left': {'left': [3, 4], 'right': [5, 6]}, 'right': {'left': {'left': [7, 8], 'right': [9, 10]}, 'right': [11, 12]}}}
```

---

Regarding second point, I am not exactly sure myself of the best way to go about it, it depends on what exact operations you expect form the data structure.

One idea is using classes. Might be slightly over engineered for your problem but you can fully traverse through the tree by taking the `Tree.parent`, `Tree.right`, `Tree.left`:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, data=None, level=0):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None
        
        self.data = data
        self.level = level
    
    def set_left_right(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    
    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent


    def __str__(self):

        if self.data == None:
            data = "*{}*".format(self.level)
        else:
            data = self.data

        if self.left != None and self.right != None:
            return "[{}]<-({})->[{}]".format(self.left, data, self.right)
        elif self.left != None:
            return "[{}]<-({})".format(self.left, data)
        elif self.right != None:
            return "({})->[{}]".format(data, self.right)
        else:
            return "({})".format(data)




def tree3(data, min_size=2, level=0):
    
    if (len(data) < 2*min_size):  
        return Tree(data, level=level)
        
    else:
        
        lhs, rhs = _split(data,min_size)

        lhs = tree3(lhs, min_size,level+1)
        rhs = tree3(rhs, min_size,level+1)

        out = Tree(level=level)
        lhs.set_parent(out)
        rhs.set_parent(out)

        out.set_left_right(lhs, rhs)

        return out


print(tree3([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]))
```

Output:

```
[[[([1, 2])]<-(*2*)->[([3, 4, 5])]]<-(*1*)->[([6, 7])]]<-(*0*)->[[([8, 9, 10])]<-(*1*)->[([11, 12])]]
```